# Identify if windows server is dedicated or vps

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, vps, dedicated-server

I have offers for vps and dedicated hosting.

The price for dedicated server is around $100/month which makes me think whether I am really getting a dedicated machine or just scammed to give me vps in the name of dedicated server.

Is their anything **windows 2008 specific that we can check whether is a dedicated machine or vps**?

Something from device manager or remote bios or something of that sort?

Note -

1. answer could not be to ask the provider as I want to believe on facts rather than words.
2. Nothing great can be identified from lan like ipconfig /all nor any of the linux commands works on windows shell.
3. As a technology believer No should be last thing we have :)

Comment: check for known VM device drivers?

Comment: That price is not wrong for a dedicated server. But it is too high for a VPS.

Comment: Well i thought getting quad core cpu with 12 gb ram dedicated 1 gbps line in $100/m was cheap! am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a while ago I found this doc on the internet about vm detection [VMDE](http://www.heise.de/security/downloads/07/1/1/8/3/5/5/9/vmde.pdf). Maybe this could help you.

Comment: I guess it does not answer hyper-v based vps issues?

Comment: Hyper-V is not mentioned directly, but I'm pretty sure the tests will also work on hyper-v guests or vps (e.g. end of page 10, quote from MS). Maybe there is something like 30-day test period, which you can use to run the tests?